# How do I disable the middle mouse button click?

Tags: windows-10, mouse, mouse-wheel

My mouse is buggy and the middle mouse button is always pressed and I dont know how I disable the click function.

I have looked at my mouse settings and I cant change the middle mouse function at all.

I still want to be able to scroll but I want to disable the middle mouse click.

I really need a way to disable it because it blocks all the other mouse inputs so I can't move windows or click anywhere on the screen.

I have the `World of Warcraft Legendary Edition Mouse` and the default driver does not have a feature for remapping the buttons.

Comment: If you want to disable it only in Google Chrome, you could look at this question http://superuser.com/questions/44418/how-to-disable-the-middle-button-scrolling-in-chrome

Comment: The middle mouse button is broken kind of, and it just makes it harder to use the computer and I want a way to disable it.

Comment: Buy a new mouse.

Comment: Please add a tag for your operating system (Windows, ...)

Comment: Some mouse drivers allow button reassignment. You should include your mouse make/model in your question.

Comment: I know that those mouses have some sort of sentimental attachment, and they look really cool - more for a WoW fan, even so. But, really - the best you can do is to put that one to rest, maybe on a frame on your wall, as a keepsake. Buy a new gaming mouse, you won't regret it!

Comment: @Thales Your comment was good and i'm probably going to get a new mouse now. And thanks to everyone that commented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most mice are easily disassembled and fixed; I've done so more than once.

You will need a small screwdriver (e.g. those in eyeglass repair kits) and fine-tipped tweezers. Find an assembly diagram for the particular model, or just look for a screw or two on the bottom, sometimes hidden by a label or underneath PTFE pads (used to make the mouse glide better).

Remove the screw(s) and *gently, slowly* pry top from bottom, being careful not to drop loose parts inside -- note where the parts go, such as between button and microswitch.

If the middle mouse switch has an open spring, *carefully* bend the spring so it presses up against the wheel a bit harder. Alternatively, push a bit of springy closed-cell plastic foam between the switch and wheel so as to increase the force needed to depress the switch.

Reassemble and test.

This is *far* more satisfactory than disabling a useful switch.

However, you *can* disable the switch in *hardware*, if you must: use the tweezers to repeatedly bend and finally break off a wire going to the wheel switch. This "fix" will work with all computers and all OS's.

Answer (score 6):

Install this softrware https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/xmousebuttoncontrol.htm
and u have option do disable it or add new function to it.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 4):

Download and install Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard Center. From this application you can easily assign new tasks to mouse buttons including middle button or completely disable it.

Comment: Seemed like a great option (although 50MB to change the function of a mouse button seems pretty bloated) - until it said I had no supported devices.  I'm using a super basic $9 mouse from Amazon.  Uninstalled.

Comment: elPastor, you're not alone. It says I have no supported devices, either, even though I'm using a genuine Microsoft mouse. (Device Manager calls my mouse "Microsoft USB Wheel Mouse Optical," and the Device Instance Path is HID\VID_045E&PID_0040\7&239BEB47&0&0000.)

Answer (score 1):

Use screwdriver to open the mouse, then use combination pliers / tongs to remove upper part of the switcher that is below the wheel. (Of course there is some risk you damage something while doing so, but if do it carefuly chances are minimum)

You can then remove metalic part that is inside the switcher that way even if you click, the electrical circuit will not get connected which means there will be no electrical signal for the computer to do the middle click)